# Java Selenium Invalid Xpath Statement

Tags: java, selenium, xpath

I am having an issue locating an element by xpath.
I am trying to find a th (table header)element with the text "Team A" which is nested inside a div tag with a class='left-Side'.

I would be very grateful if someone could advise on how to correctly structure this statement:

`webDriver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='left-Side'] and .//th[contains(text(),'Team A')]"));`

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The **and** condition should be under square bracket `[ ]`. Replace xpath as mentioned below:

```
//div[@class='left-Side' and .//th[contains(text(),'Team A')]]
```